# Identity Server 4 with .NET MVC 4.8, the length of the query string for this query is greater than the configured maxQueryStringLength value Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, identityserver4, owin-middleware

I have a website that is hosted in Local IIS witch is configured as a client in Identity server 4 , my problem is that i'm getting this message `The length of the query string for this query is greater than the configured maxQueryStringLength value.` when try to login using identity server 4.

Knowing that I have changed this property in the web.config to put it to the maximum.

```
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="4294967295"  />
</requestFiltering>
```

Here is the code in the start up of my website:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        // app.Use<SawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler>();
        app.UseSawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "Website.UI",
            Authority = "https://localhost:5001",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost/MyWebsite.Test",
            ResponseType = "code",
            Scope = "openid profile offline_access api",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            RedeemCode = true,
            SaveTokens = true,
            ResponseMode = "query",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                    {
                        var state = context.ProtocolMessage.State;

                        // set PKCE parameters
                        var codeVerifier = CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(8);

                        string codeChallenge;
                        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
                        {
                            var challengeBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
                            codeChallenge = Base64Url.Encode(challengeBytes);
                        }
                                context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("code_challenge", codeChallenge);
                            context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("code_challenge_method", "S256");

                        // remember code_verifier (adapted from OWIN nonce cookie)
                        RememberCodeVerifier(context, codeVerifier);
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ProtocolMessage.State) ||
                               context.ProtocolMessage.State.StartsWith("OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties="))
                    {
                        var authenticationPropertiesString = context.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=')[1];

                        AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties = context.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(authenticationPropertiesString);

                        return Task.FromResult(authenticationProperties.RedirectUri);
                    }
                    return Task.Delay(0);
                },
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                {
                    // get code_verifier
                    var codeVerifier = RetrieveCodeVerifier(context);

                    // attach code_verifier
                    context.TokenEndpointRequest.SetParameter("code_verifier", codeVerifier);

                    return Task.Delay(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the code in identity server side :

```
 "Clients": [{
        "ClientId": "Website.UI",
        "RequireConsent": false,
        "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "authorization_code" ],
        "RequirePkce": true,
        "RequireClientSecret": false,
        "RedirectUris": [ "https://localhost/MyWebsite.Test"],
        "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "api" ],
        "AllowOfflineAccess": true,
        "AllowedCorsOrigins": ["https://localhost:44300"]
      }}
```

When i investigated i found the execute this below three time

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                        {..}
```

which makes the  "`State": "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=`    too big

Comment: According to the Microsoft documentation the [`maxQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/) default value is `2048`. Therefore try to define some reasonable value in you `web.config` file. For example `maxQueryString="10240"`.

Comment: This value maxQueryString="10240" is too small may problem is that i get a big response from Identity server that exceeds even this number maxQueryString="4294967295" .

Comment: I assume the parameter `maxQueryString` is not the problem. It is unlikely that the Identity Server will send you responses of size > 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

When you have this setting:

ResponseMode = "query",

Then the query string will be quite big. One option is to use ResponseMode ="form_post" instead to avoid getting this error.

Comment: Thanks for your response but when i change it to that ResponseMode ="form_post" i'm calling Identity server in an infinite loop.